# Quando devo "fechar" um travessão?

Tags: pontuação

Enquanto estava respondendo em um [outro site desta rede](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/427904/69296), acabei escrevendo a seguinte frase:

> Assim, se você quiser formatar o mesmo horário de antes **–** 3 horas e 8 minutos PM, utilizando esse novo padrão, você terá:

Note na frase acima que eu tenho um travessão, e algumas palavras depois, vem uma vírgula (depois de `PM`). A questão é que antes daquela vírgula, o "bloco semântico" daquele travessão teria acabado. Então fiquei na dúvida. Deveria tê-la fechado naquela posição ou a vírgula já está fazendo esse papel?

---

P.S.: Quando digo "fechar o travessão", refiro-me a isto:

> Assim, se você quiser formatar o mesmo horário de antes **–** 3 horas e 8 minutos PM **–**, utilizando esse novo padrão, você terá:

Comment: A frase *"se você quiser formatar..."* é uma oração adverbial condicional deslocada, logo a vírgula é obrigatória, mesmo que seja imediatamente após o travessão (utilizado para dar ênfase à informação) ou parêntese. No entanto, a vírgula após o termo PM estará incorreta (independente se usar, ou não, o travessão). Por conseguinte, o correto é *"Assim, se você quiser formatar o mesmo horário de antes – 3 horas e 8 minutos PM – utilizando esse novo padrão, você terá:"*

Comment: @ValdeirPsr este comentário foi muito bom.  Se eu pudesse dar 10 votos dava... Acho até que devia ser reposta em vez de comentário, pois merece.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, obrigado pelo "comentário-resposta"! Se você quiser transcrevê-lo para uma resposta, ficarei feliz em aceitá-la. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A frase *"se você quiser formatar..."* é uma oração adverbial condicional deslocada, logo a vírgula é obrigatória, mesmo que seja imediatamente após o travessão (utilizado para dar ênfase à informação) ou parêntese.

No entanto, a vírgula após o termo *PM* é facultativa, pois a oração *utilizando esse novo padrão* tem a função adverbial e está na ordem direta *(Sujeito + Verbo [+ Complemento Verbal, + Adjunto Adverbial, + Adjunto Adnominal])*

Por conseguinte, o correto é:

> - "Assim, se você quiser formatar o mesmo horário de antes – 3 horas e 8 minutos PM – utilizando esse novo padrão, você terá:"
> - "Assim, se você quiser formatar o mesmo horário de antes – 3 horas e 8 minutos PM –, utilizando esse novo padrão, você terá:"
> - "Assim, se você quiser formatar o mesmo horário de antes, 3 horas e 8 minutos PM, utilizando esse novo padrão, você terá:"
> - "Assim, se você quiser formatar o mesmo horário de antes (3 horas e 8 minutos PM) utilizando esse novo padrão, você terá:"
> - "Assim, se você quiser formatar o mesmo horário de antes (3 horas e 8 minutos PM), utilizando esse novo padrão, você terá:"

Comment: Aproveitei e fiz uma correção quanto à posição da vírgula após PM